# Result set always returns empty, should I not use executeQuery() on my prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, resultset

I've got users trying to register to a site. before they can register their username of choice is searched for in an SQL database to make sure it doesn't already exist. 
the problem is the names are never searched because the ResultSet always returns empty. I think it's the prepared statement.

I think my prepared statement isn't executing. I'm using `executeQuery()` to execute my statement because that's how I've been inserting the usernames without any problem. I got the search ResultsSet part `if (rs.next())...` from the method that inserts the usernames. Same with the `String SQL` and the prepared statement stuff.

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + getUsername() + "'";

    System.out.println(SQL);
    // prints out SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='whatever I searched'
    // so this String is valid
    if (db.getConn() != null){
        System.out.println("connected to database");
        // always prints
    }
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = db.getConn().prepareStatement(SQL);
   // preparedStatement.setString(1, getUsername());
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
//    userNameCounter = rs.getString("username");
    // putting this here returns an sqlexception. empty set
if (preparedStatement != null){
        System.out.println("ps != null");
        // prints this
    }
    if (rs != null){
        System.out.println("rs != null");
        // prints this
    }
    if (!rs.next()){
        System.out.println("!rs.next");
        // prints this
    }
    if (rs.next()) {
        userNameCounter = rs.getString("username");
        System.out.println("rs.next()");
        // doesn't print
        // so the resultset is empty

        if (!userNameCounter.equals(getUsername())) {
            System.out.println("that username is unique");
            return true;
        }
    }
    preparedStatement.close();
    incorrectLabels.setText("That username is already taken");
    incorrectLabels.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("that username is already there");
    // this always prints. it shouldn't
    return false;
```

So `executeUpdate()` requires an `int` but I'm not sure what I would put there. And doing just `execute()` throws an error `Requires ResultSet found boolean`. I don't think there are any syntax errors since the table is called `users`. Everything I try just leads me back to an error resulting from an empty set. let me know if you need more code but this is where the error is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: You should prepare your statement **with placeholder values**. This has a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) in it.

Comment: Why not print `getUserName()`?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus `getUserName()` prints the correct username.

Comment: @tadman The issue isn't an injection bug and when I change to placeholders then print the `String SQL` it prints SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?  not sure if the '?' should be printing as the searched username or not. also doesn't fix the empty result set

Comment: If the result set is empty, it simply means that there is no user with the given user name.

Comment: @JBNizet result set is always empty. Even if there is a repeat username.

Comment: Well, check your assumptions. Maybe the users that you see in your table haven't been committed yet. Maybe they have a space at the end of their name. Maybe the submitted name has a space. Maybe the URL of your database is pointing to another database than the one you're looking at.

Comment: @JBNizet there are 3 usernames. all 3 have been committed. user1, user2, user3. no spaces. all 3 results sets return empty. There is only one database.

Comment: Do you get the result you expect in a psql session?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Sorry. I don't know what that is.

Comment: Sorry, misread which DB you are using. psql is the interactive shell into Postgres. MySQL must have a shell, too.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus yeah I can do queries and find usernames. I get the expected result

Comment: How many rows do you get when you do `SELECT * FROM users` with no `WHERE` clause? What are the `username` values?

Comment: @tadman well I commented all this out and have been testing the automated emails and have I have created 47 username values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing a query to the database when using the SELECT statement therefore you use the executeQuery() method.

What looks confusing is the **userNameCounter** variable you're using. Where is it declared and what is it declared as? It looks like it may be a Integer variable which would bring me to ask....what do you think the rs.getString("username") method returns?
As a matter of fact...what's with all the **rs.next()** conditions for all those **if** statements?

The whole thing is rather confusing. If you want to see if a User Name already exists within a database table then you might do it something like this:

```
if (db.getConn() == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("Method Error! You Are NOT Connected To Database!");
}

String suppliedUserName = getUsername();
String dbUserName = "";
String SQL = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = db.getConn().prepareStatement(SQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, suppliedUserName);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    dbUserName = rs.getString("username");
}
rs.close()
preparedStatement.close()

/* Below we use the equalsIgnoreCase() method. You 
   don't want a supplied User Name to be that close 
   or that similar to another User Name already in 
   Database. If you do then just use equals() method.  */
if (dbUserName.equalsIgnoreCase(suppliedUserName)) {
    System.out.println("The User name (" + suppliedUserName + 
                ") is already in use. Try another User Name.");
    return false;
}
else {
    System.out.println("The User name (" + suppliedUserName + ") is Unique.");
    return true;
}
```

Of course this code isn't tested and I assume you have your **try/catch** in place to handle any **SQLException**. I merely provide this code to give you an idea of how it can be accomplished.

Comment: Yeah I can see how it can be confusing. All the `rs.next()` stuff and printing it and what not was just for me to see where it was going wrong. and I thought it might be helpful to show others what I've tried/where I've pinpointed the problem. thanks for the help! it solved my problem!